# Python, How to find the right indent level when the openning of desired indent level is not visible in a screen?

Tags: python

say you have

```
    for user_id, group in df.sort_values(
          ['user_id', 'timestamp'], ascending=[True, False]
     ).groupby('user_id'):
         group = group.reset_index()
         positive = None
         for index, row in group.iterrows():
             # print(index)
             if row.rating_type not in [20, 90]:
                 positive = row

                 num_prior = self.num_prior
                 low = max(0, index - num_prior)
                 priors = group.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id', 'review_meta_id'])[low:index]

                 result_positive_dict = {
                     'user_id': user_id,
                     'review_meta_id': positive.review_meta_id,
                     'prior_ids': ','.join(priors.review_meta_id),
                     'target': 1
                 }
                 results.append(result_positive_dict)
                 # 20, 90 = negative
                 positives = group[(group.index>=index) & (~group.rating_type.isin([20, 90]))][:10]

                 num_negative = 4

                 for i in range(num_negative):
                     index_sample = random.sample(range(index+1), 1)[0]
                     sample = group.iloc[index_sample]

                     low = max(0, index_sample - num_prior)

                     try_count = 5
                     for _ in range(try_count):
                         if sample.rating_type not in [20, 90] or sample.review_meta_id in positives.review_meta_id:
                             index_sample = random.sample(range(index+1), 1)[0]
```

....

after few more lines, your screen doesn't show the first line `for user_id, group in df.sort_values(` which has the right indent level you want..

How do you place your cursor at the right indentation level in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

For Python, I recommend [`elpy-mode`](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy).  It has vertical guides for this, by default.

[image: junk]

There is also `python-mode` (required by `elpy-mode`) which automatically cycles through the various indentation levels using `<TAB>`.  If it gets too confusing to track indentations, I would consider that a code smell.  Maybe think about refactoring.

There are also a slew of options, all falling into the category of "put the code you want on the screen".

These include:

1. Recentering with `C-l` (`recenter-top-bottom`)
2. Opening a new window with `C-x 2` (`split-window-below`) or `C-x 3` (`split-window-right`) and visit the file in each window.  The code in each window can be "out of sync" with one another.
3. Make the text smaller with `C-x C--` (`text-scale-adjust`)
4. Fold the code with `hs-mode`